# What is the opposite of "peaked"?

Tags: single-word-requests

My productivity reached a maximum in middle school:

> My productivity **peaked** in middle school.

However, my productivity reached a minimum in university:

> My productivity **[insert word]** in university.

What is the opposite of "peaked"?

The opposite of a peak is a valley, crater, or trough. "Valleyed" and "troughed" do not seem correct. "Cratered" implies a steep and sudden decline, which is not what I want to say.

"Nose-dived", "plummeted", "declined", "slumped", "decreased", etc. are not suitable because they do not imply that the minimum has been reached.

Any clues?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more frequently used and colloquial expression is *bottom out*, which means "to reach a point where a decline is halted or reversed" ([MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottom)), or "to have reached the lowest point in a continuously changing situation and to be about to improve" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bottom-out)).

*My productivity **bottomed out** at the university*.

As @Mari-Lou A has suggested in the comments, a related expression, *hit rock bottom*, could also work. It means "to reach the lowest possible level" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rock-bottom)).

*My productivity **hit rock bottom** at the university.*

This variant doesn't seem to imply the possibility of a subsequent improvement implied by *bottom out*.

Comment: I'd prefer "**hit rock bottom**" I think that is more commonly heard, at least when I was a student.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you're right. That's another possibility. I suggested _bottomed out_ because I think it may leave a bit more hope for improvement. But _hit rock bottom_ is good.

Comment: Feel free to add it, it wouldn't have come to my mind if I hadn't seen your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I think "bottomed out at university" could definitely have a ribald interpretation.

Comment: Good exchange with @Mari-LouA …

Answer (score 1):

It's not a single word, but I'd say *to reach a nadir*

See [meaning 2 of this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir) (and the example sentence: *Nantucket reached its nadir in the post-Civil War period. The whaling industry had become moribund, ...*)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would probably be

> *My productivity reached the minimum at the university.*

or

> *My productivity fell to its lowest levels at the university*.

However, these examples are not as... passionate, probably... as *"My productivity peaked at middle school"*. [Merriam-Webster suggests](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/peaked) **collapsed** as an antonym of *"peaked"*, and, to my mind, the word does its job pretty well: [it is impossible to half-collapse or collapse not to the very minimum](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/collapse), it is considerably passionate, and it sounds natural. Thus, better solution would be to say:

> *My productivity collapsed at the university*.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

There is **cratered**. It may be considered parallel to **peaked**.

> **crater** VERB
>   ...
>   1.1 *[no object]* Drop or fall suddenly and disastrously; collapse.
>   [LEXICO](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crater)

Comment: Is 'My performance cratered' acceptable on grounds of idiomaticity? Are there examples of this metaphorical usage?

Comment: As I explicitly mentioned in the question, "cratered" is not suitable because I do not want to imply that the decline was sudden.